# Redux Uncaught type error: dispatched action is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I feel like I'm missing something simple here, but for whatever reason this simple ErrorMessageAlert won't dispatch an action.  I've dispatched many times and I can't seem to figure out this error.

Can anyone lend a second pair of eyes?

Here's my Component

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import styled from 'react-emotion';
import { resetErrorMessage } from 'users/ducks'


const ErrorMessage = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    color: red;
    position: fixed;
    background: #F9DADA;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
`

export class ErrorMessageAlert extends Component<props> {

    state = {  isHidden: true }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("triggered")
        // debugger
        const { resetErrorMessageAction } = this.props
        resetErrorMessageAction()
    }

    render(){

        const {
            errorMessage,
        } = this.props

        console.log(this.state.isHidden)
            return (
                <div>
                    {
                        this.state.isHidden && <ErrorMessage>{errorMessage}</ErrorMessage>
                    }
                </div>
            )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    resetErrorMessageAction: () => dispatch(resetErrorMessage()),
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ErrorMessageAlert);
```

in users/ducks

```
export const RESET_ERROR_MESSAGE = 'RESET_ERROR_MESSAGE';

export const resetErrorMessage = () => ({
    type: RESET_ERROR_MESSAGE,
})
```

Here's the main error message stack trace:

````
ErrorMessageAlert.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: resetErrorMessageAction is not a function
    at ErrorMessageAlert.componentDidMount (ErrorMessageAlert.js:29)
    at ErrorMessageAlert.componentDidMount (react-hot-loader.development.js:654)
    at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:17334)
    at commitAllLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:18736)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:18948)
    at react-dom.development.js:20418
    at Object.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:255)
    ```
````

Comment: In `componentDidMount`, are you able to put a `debugger` statement, or some king of logging, to see what `resetErrorMessageAction` is?

Comment: just out of curious, can you share your code for resetErrorMessage()?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo just posted the ducks files

Comment: @OliverRadini hitting debugger and then executing `resetErrorMessageActiono()` yields the stack trace I just gave.

Comment: @gary1410 Yes, if you hit the line that calls the function then you'll get the same error. Posting the `ducks` file is handy but that doesn't tell us what `resetErrorMessageAction` is, as it comes in from `props`. Before you hit that line, you should see what it is, because you're trying to use it as a function, and it isn't a function

Comment: @OliverRadini `resetErrorMessageAction` (and not the function) says it's undefined.

Comment: Ugh!  I imported it as a named import.  i.e 
`import { ErrorMessageAlert } from 'error/ErrorMessageAlert';` instead of
`import ErrorMessageAlert from 'error/ErrorMessageAlert';

it was a default export so therefore I can't use the curlies.  Ugghhh.  Thanks for being a rubber duck.

Answer (score 0):

`resetErrorMessageAction` is `undefined` because I had imported it incorrectly from a different file since I was using an export defaulted function.

So you need to correctly import the file.

```
import { ErrorMessageAlert } from 'error/ErrorMessageAlert';
```

vs

```
import ErrorMessageAlert from 'error/ErrorMessageAlert';
```